# JWT token disappears and returns undefined in console

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, authorization

These past days I've been trying to get into JWT for a project I'm currently working on. I wanna use JWT to use private routes that only people who are logged in can access and with and a person to get logged out after a certain amount of time, like { expiresIn } provides. But my problem is that my token only appears in the console and document on the post page, but disappears and returns undefined in the console when I go to another page.

Comment: Please paste some code you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the JWT token in browser as a cookie.

```
res.cookie("token", token, { expire: new Date() + 9999 });
```

Try using cookie parser https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser
You can also delete the cookie during signout

```
res.clearCookie('token');
```